# How to setup Netflix Eureka

Tags: netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka, netflix, spring-cloud-netflix

is there any tutorial/example which shows me step by step how to setup a eureka server cluster and a eureka zuul cluster which forwards my requests to my microservices? The netflix documentation is sometimes a bit old and overall very bad and the spring cloud integration does not show any clustered examples.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find one guide that showed both Zuul and Eureka but there were two Spring guides that cover both topics. With a little magic I don't think it would be too hard to understand how Zuul and Eureka can work together.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/

https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/